# Insert paste keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard

Is there a keyboard shortcut that would set the cursor to the start of a section of text which has just been pasted? The default behaviour is for the cursor to appear after the pasted text.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, could you clarify a bit?

Comment: @JacobVlijm something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/1587178/2072269, but more general.

Comment: I would use autohotkey , It should be capable of simulating Ctrl+V, counting number of characters in clipboard and then skip back by that number. I have never used autohotkey, so I would have to learn autohotkey scripting myself. Than you would invoke that script with for example Ctrl+L...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not such a general feature in Ubuntu. There may be some keybindings like this in specific applications, though.

Just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste, then move word by word with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>◂</kbd>.